# Invalid frame dimension, invalid data found when processing input, muxing overhead: unknown when concatting old VOB files | FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mpeg-2

I am dealing with multiple errors which I am not able to resolve. I am trying to concat 4 old VOB files to a mp4. Using command (already solved a 'pts has no value error'):

```
.\ffmpeg.exe -fflags +genpts -f concat -i .\files.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

files.txt looks like this:

```
file 'VTS_01_1.VOB'
file 'VTS_01_2.VOB'
file 'VTS_01_3.VOB'
file 'VTS_01_4.VOB'
```

Output looks like this:

```
ffmpeg version 2023-03-05-git-912ac82a3c-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libvpl --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavcodec     60.  6.100 / 60.  6.100
  libavformat    60.  4.100 / 60.  4.100
  libavdevice    60.  2.100 / 60.  2.100
  libavfilter     9.  4.100 /  9.  4.100
  libswscale      7.  2.100 /  7.  2.100
  libswresample   4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
  libpostproc    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
Input #0, concat, from '.\files.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Data: dvd_nav_packet
  Stream #0:1: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, top first), 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 7000000/0/0 buffer size: 1835008 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:2: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 448 kb/s
File 'output.mp4' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
[mp4 @ 00000211b44d0900] track 1: codec frame size is not set
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf60.4.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video (Main) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p(tv, top first), 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 7000000/0/0 buffer size: 1835008 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1: Audio: ac3 (ac-3 / 0x332D6361), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 448 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mpeg2video @ 00000211b44a5f00] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0. bitrate=5521.6kbits/s speed= 643x
    Last message repeated 3 times
[concat @ 00000211b449b500] DTS 137507370 < 137525388 out of order
[mp4 @ 00000211b44d0900] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 137525388, current: 137507370; changing to 137525389. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000211b44d0900] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 137525389, current: 137510250; changing to 137525390. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000211b44d0900] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 137525390, current: 137510250; changing to 137525391. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000211b44d0900] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 137525391, current: 137513130; changing to 137525392. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000211b44d0900] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 137525392, current: 137516010; changing to 137525393. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000211b44d0900] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 137525393, current: 137518890; changing to 137525394. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000211b44d0900] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 137525394, current: 137521770; changing to 137525395. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000211b44d0900] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 137525395, current: 137524650; changing to 137525396. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid data found when processing input
[out#0/mp4 @ 00000211b44f96c0] Error muxing a packet
[out#0/mp4 @ 00000211b44f96c0] Error writing trailer: Invalid data found when processing input
frame=45815 fps=19808 q=-1.0 Lsize= 1027328kB time=00:25:29.51 bitrate=5502.3kbits/s speed= 661x
video:943791kB audio:83556kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: It's possible that you can't just copy a codec from VOB and paste into MP4. I don't think MP4 carries AC3 audio. Options: **(1)** Slower but works... Remove `-c copy` and see if you get a playable file. **(2)** Faster but not guaranteed to play everywhere... Try as `-c copy output.mov`

Comment: It looks like removing -c copy is the only way to solve this. The original file is probably corrupted in some way. Trying -c copy to a .mov file did not help unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestions!